# Scala: How to transform a POJO like object into a SQL insert statement using Scala reflection

Tags: sql, scala, reflection

I'm facing this (at least for me) interesting task: getting a SQL insert statement from a POJO like object. Let me say I don't need to add a framework between my Scala application and the DB because I just need to insert data into a single DB table.

So, supposing the attributes of my class are named equally to those of the DB table, I'd like to use Scala reflection in order to get from a class like this one

```
class MyDataObj {
   var a:Int = 345
   var b:Boolean = false
   var c:Double = 1243.98
   var d:String = "A random string"
}
```

a SQL insert statement like this

```
INSERT INTO table_a (a, b, c, d) values (345, false, 1243.98, 'A random String');
```

Well, what we need is
1) access to the class attributes
2) access to the attribute types
3) access to the attribute values of the object instance

In order to get something like this

```
List( ("a","Int",345), ("b","Boolean",false), ("c","Double",1243.98), ... )
```

that will be easy to transform into what we want.

Up to now, I've just found out how to access to the attributes names

```
val columns = typeOf[MyDataObj].members.view.filter{_.isTerm}.
                filter{!_.isMethod}.map{_.name}.toList
```

How can I get the rest I need?

Thanks as usual for supporting me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you can use the following codes:

```
val o = new MyDataObj
val attributes = o.getClass.getDeclaredMethods.filter {
  _.getReturnType != Void.TYPE
}.map {
  method => (method.getName, method.getReturnType, method.invoke(o))
}
```

Here I use `getDeclaredMethods` to get the public methods in the `MyDataObj`. You need to notice that `getDeclaredMethods` can not get methods in its parent class.

For `MyDataObj`, `getDeclaredMethods` will return the following methods:

```
public double MyDataObj.c()
public boolean MyDataObj.b()
public java.lang.String MyDataObj.d()
public int MyDataObj.a()
public void MyDataObj.c_$eq(double)
public void MyDataObj.d_$eq(java.lang.String)
public void MyDataObj.b_$eq(boolean)
public void MyDataObj.a_$eq(int)
```

So I add a filter to filter out irrelevant methods.